# JIbri | I have changed the entries in sip-communicator.properties, but jibri is not reflecting it

Tags: linux, jitsi, jitsi-meet

So, I made a mistake in the `/etc/jitsi/jicofo/sip-communicator.properties` file, I fixed it later on, but even after making the changes and restarting all the services, it isn't reflecting in `jibri` which gives me an error:

**`Can not join 'jibribrewery@auth.example.org', because 'auth.example.org' does not provide a MUC (XEP-45) service."`**

Whereas I have changed it to "`internal.auth.example.org`"
Please help me fix it.

Answer (score 0):

try removing the previous jibri config. In my case it is present in `~/.jitsi-meet-cfg/jibri`

Comment: Can you check the value of `CONFIG` in `.env` file?